# Multiple Tablix that are different from each other with multiple lines of data per tablix using the same dataset in one report

Tags: listview, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have an SSRS report that contains 3 Tablix using the SAME dataset. The first 2 Tablix have an Employee Filter of "E" and the 3rd Tablix has an Employee Filter of "D". Each of the 3 Tablix have a parent group of EmployeeName.

When I run the report for 1 person, everything shows up as desired on one page showing only the information for the one employee in each respective tablix. When I choose 2 employees, each tablix shows each employee one after the other instead of 1 employee on one page, the second employee on page 2 etc.

How do I get one employees information per page for all 3 tablixs.

I have tried the ListView and Rectangle with the same results.

I want to get one employees information per page for all 3 tablixs.

Answer (score 0):

I find the easiet way to do this is with sub-reports.

Make a backup of your current report before you start...

Now edit the current report so it only accepts a single employee as oyu know that works OK. Save the report and call it something like `subEmpReport`

Next create a new blank report.

Now create a dataset that just contains a list of unique Employees selected. I'll assume that this is an ID field called `employeeID` for simplicity, and that your employee parameter is called `empID`.

So the query for your dataset (called `dsEmpList` for this example) would be something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT employeeID 
    FROM myEmployeeTable 
    WHERE employeeID = @empID
```

This will create a parameter for you, set this parameter up just like on your original report, so that it shows a list of employees and is multi-valued.

Now create a table on your report design and sets it's dataset to `dsEmpList` (the dataset we just created).

Remove all rows and columns from the table except one, so you'll just have a single 'cell' left. Expand this cell so it's the width of your report.

Now right click the cell and do `Insert => Sub report`.
Right-click this new subreport placeholder and choose properties. 
Set the subreport to `subEmpReport` we created at the start.
GO to the parameters tab in the same dialogue box and set the parameter name to the name of the parameter in your **subreport**. Set the value from the drop down which should just be `employeeID` (this is the field name from the `dsEmpList` created earlier.

Besides a bit of formatting that should be it.

When the report runs,  the 'master' report will run, creating a row in the table for each employee record in `dsEmpList`, each row will contain your subreport and each sub report will have the employeeID passed in.

Comment: i tried the sub-reports and it is doing the same thing...showing the employee information all together for each sub-report. So if I select employee #1 (is there a way to put pictures on here), the main report and the 2 sub-reports only show the one employees information which is great.  If I select a second employee with the first employee, the first and second employee show up in the main report back to back, then the 1st sup report back to back, and the 3rd sub-report back to back

Comment: If you subreport only allows a single employee then that cannot happen. In the first steps I state you must do that. I've been doing reports just like that for over 15 years and never have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Sub-reports WITHIN the Tablix and Group that you are reporting on. This will allow the employees to keep their data together in a group individually.